# Eclipse Android shortcut for content assist in XML

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, autocomplete, shortcut

While editing an XML layout file, I would like Eclipse to display content proposals.

E.g. when I type in "marg" and press `Cmd+Space`, it should offer me a dropdown list of

`layout_marginLeft`, `layout_marginRight` etc.

How can I set this keybinding?

(On Mac it is by default Ctrl+Space, but I want it to be Cmd+Space)

Comment: Cmd+Space is already used system-wide by Spotlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Command+Space` usually brings up Spotlight. You'll have to turn this off first.

1. Go to `System Preferences / Spotlight`.
2. Disable or remap `Command+Space`.

Then in Eclipse:

1. Go to `Eclipse / Preferences`.
2. Select `General / Keys`.
3. Select `Content Assist` in the list.
4. Delete the `^Space` in the binding textbox.
5. Type in `Command+Space`.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to

```
Eclipse > Preferences > Keys
```

find the option 'Content Assist' and changing the binding to cmd + space.